# PHP Namespacing error

Tags: php

I'll firstly start off by showing my code, I've tried to keep things simple for the sake of learning.

**My Code**

index.php -

```
require('autoloader.php');

$hammer = new Acme\Tools\Hammer();
```

autoloader.php -

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include $class_name . '.php';
});
```

Hammer.php -

```
namespace Acme\Tools;

class Hammer
{

    public function useTool()
    {
        echo 'You start using the hammer!';
    }

}
```

**My Problem / Error Message**

> Warning: include(Acme\Tools\Hammer.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\php\autoloader.php on line 4
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Acme\Tools\Hammer.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\autoloader.php on line 4
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Acme\Tools\Hammer' not found in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php:5 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\php\index.php on line 5

I was initially using the 'use' statement in index like the following, but changed it thinking it would help.

old index.php -

```
use Acme\Tools;

require('autoloader.php');

$hammer = new Tools\Hammer();
```

Does anyone know why either isn't working?

Comment: What's unclear in a phrase `No such file or directory`?

Comment: where did you place Hammer.php?

Comment: @IvoP its all within the same directory

Comment: @u_mulder I can read, but like i said im not sure what the error is, im also new to namespacing and autoloading as you can imagine, everything is in the same directory. But i think its trying to autoload the namespaced directory. Im not sure how to make it pull a namespaced directory.

Answer (score 2):

Your autoloader is assuming that the full class name is the full path of the class file.  You will need to prefix it with the root directory of your class path.  `__DIR__` in this example assumes the class path starts where your script is run from, but you will need to change it to reflect the proper path:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    include __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class_name) . '.php';
});
```

This is a very primitive autoloader example.  If you want to use the current established method for autoloading, do a bit of research into [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/).

Comment: +1 for Composer. The chances are you don't need the code you already have to do the auto-loading when there are established things such as Composer that can take care of this in a better way.

Comment: But if i dont understand autoloading, why would i jump deep into composer autoloader?

Comment: @YasminFrench Thats a good point, its more advanced and you'll need to know how autoloading works before delving into it since Composer has its own head-aches.  But thats your target path of progression, and the code above should solve your current problem.

Comment: @Flosculus thanks, i've used this but still get the same error. I think its cause its looking for a namespaced directory?

Comment: I thought you might, if you used this as is, but I don't know what your directory structure looks like.

Comment: @Flosculus I've put everything in the same folder just to keep it simple

Comment: Is this where you class lives? `C:\xampp\htdocs\php\Acme\Tools\Hammer.php`

Comment: @Flosculus no, i was under the assumption that the namespaces didn't have to be a physical directory and was just used for preventing name collisions? But the more i get answers im starting to feel like i was wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148786/discussion-between-flosculus-and-yasmin-french).

Answer (score 0):

when all is in the same dir:
strip the whole name space

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class_name) {
    $file = preg_match('#[^\\](.*)$#', $class_name, $a);
    include $a[1] . '.php';
});
```

would be making more sense if you place the file in /acme/Tools/Hammer.php

Comment: that assumes that over the life of the project the file structure will be constant.  Might as well have the well formed include ( __DIR__) off the get-go.

Comment: yes the structure would remain constant. Or else you have to change the autoloader accordingly. That function is meant to find the scripts using some kind of logic. Namespace usually is part of that logic

Answer (score 0):

just a small addition to @Flosculus answer above :

```
/**
 *    our register function :
 *    requires that anything that is 'name spaceable' be in a
 *      php file, one per item.
 *
 *    requires that the directory structure matches EXACTLY (case)
 *      the namespace requirement.
 *
 */

spl_autoload_register(
    function ($name) {
        $name = str_replace("\\" , DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR , $name);
        $fqn  = __DIR__ . "/" . $name . ".php";
        /** @noinspection PhpIncludeInspection */
        require_once $fqn;

    }
);
```

when breaking , this is what i get in the debug session window

[image]